# No templates Visual Studio 2017 RC on win 7?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS2017 RC on windows 7 64bits, all components

[there's no templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAWMY.png)

but there's no templates to start a project even if i search in new Main Page and explore

what could be?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall all suite was the solution.